# How can I update the state (refresh) of a single list tile?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-widget

I have a setting page displaying a list view and each list tile displays the name of a user and a percentage which can be edited. By tapping on a list tile the user can change the percentage using a dialog.

I would like to update the state of a single list tile when the user saves the new value instead of building the entire page again (should be better for perfomance too). Is this possible?

I have already tried to export the list tile as a stateful widget (it must be stateful) and using it in my setting page but the setState() method does not work on the single tile at all. I don't know if it would somehow work with a notifier.

Here is how the page looks like (showing the dialog to set the new percentage):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbjYj.png)

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I added some code.

`setting_page.dart`

```
// this widget is called in a ListView.builder to bild the list tile.
// before creating the UserListTile widget I used to return the ListTile in 
// _buildRow and call setState() but then everything is re-built again, which is what I don't want to

Widget _buildRow(User user) {
    return UserListTile(
        user: user, userDAO: _userDAO, myPercentage: _myPercentage);
}
```

`user_list_tile.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myapp/classes/user.dart';
import 'package:myapp/database/user_dao.dart';
import 'package:numberpicker/numberpicker.dart';

class UserListTile extends StatefulWidget {
  const UserListTile(
      {Key? key,
      required this.user,
      required this.userDAO,
      required this.myPercentage})
      : super(key: key);

  final User user;
  final UserDAO userDAO;
  final ValueNotifier<double> myPercentage;

  @override
  _UserListTileState createState() => _UserListTileState();
}

class _UserListTileState extends State<UserListTile> {
  final TextStyle _biggerFont = const TextStyle(fontSize: 18);

  double _currentDoubleValue = 10.0;
  double? trailing;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    trailing = widget.user.percentage;
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        widget.user.name,
        style: _biggerFont,
      ),
      trailing: Text('${trailing} %'),
      onTap: () => _showDoubleDialog(widget.user).then((value) {
        if (value != false && value != null) {

          // some code to set the new percentage

          User _updatedUser = User(
              name: widget.user.name,
              id: widget.user.id,
              percentage: _newPercentage);
          widget.userDAO.updateData(_updatedUser);
          setState(() {}); // <- this setState does not update the single tile
        }
      }),
    );
  }

  Future _showDoubleDialog(User user) {
    _currentDoubleValue = user.percentage;
    return showDialog(
        // code to shod the dialog to edit the percentage
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: wrap the `listTile` in a stateful widget amd call setState() to refresh

Comment: Please share some of your code.
Especially where you call setState()